# How to update the value of a column in a foreign table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 tables, one of the tables is a foreign table to the other (foreign key). I want to decrease the value of the quantity column of items in the foreign table based on value of the  quantity column of the parent table.
Below is my code

model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

PAYMENT_METHOD = (
    ('CASH', 'cash'),
    ('TRANSFER', 'transfer'),
)

class ItemSold(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name


class DailySales(models.Model):
    customername = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    itemsold = models.ForeignKey(ItemSold, related_name="soldItem", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    totalprice = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    datesold = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    paymentmethod = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=PAYMENT_METHOD, default=PAYMENT_METHOD[0][0])
    havepaid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    datepaid = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Daily Sales'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customername

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.totalprice = self.rate * self.quantity
        super(DailySales, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
class DailySalesListView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = DailySalesSerializer
    queryset = DailySales.objects.all()
    name = 'Daily Sales List'
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)

    filterset_fields = ('customername','havepaid', 'datesold', 'itemsold', 'datepaid')

    def get(self, request):
        sales = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.serializer_class(instance=sales, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I haven't tried anything yet, I don't know how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the two model fields *quantity* are identical, in that case, you don't need them both. You can do that logic in your view with the help of get_query_context.

Example code:

```
class DailySales(ListView):
    model = ItemSold

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(DailySales, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         # now you need the count for each quantity model field
         dailysales_quantity = DailySales.objects.filter(field= field) # check this is correct I'm not sure
         # now you need to update the ItemsSold quantity so first get the current quantity count from ItemSold
         itemsold_quantity = ItemSold.objects.quantity.count() # make sure the last part is okay I did not have time to test this
         # now subtract the ItemSold model field (above as itemsold_quantity) by the DailySales quantity field ( above as dailysales_quantity 
         context['live_quantity'] = itemsold_quantity - dailysales_quantity # you might have to convert them into int since I didn't test this myself
         # finally return the data 
         return context
```

I hope this helps, it's not a complete solution but gets a step closer.

Comment: Not really, the two models have quantity column yes but I want to reduce the value of the quantity in ItemSold table by the value of the quantity in DailySales table

Comment: In that case, override the get_context_data method for the ItemSold and do the logic there. One way to do that would be to use two queries for each mdoels' quantity field as variables and then have a third variable which does the math and gets returned with the context.

Comment: Please can u show me a code example??

Comment: updated the answer with some sample code, although you'll need to do some work and testing yourself